# TeXstudio: Could not start default compiler: PdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, compilation-error

```
\documentclass{report}
\author{AAA}
\title{BBB}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}

    Quick Brown Fox

    \section{Assumptions}
    Cannot Jump
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ww.
        \item ee.
        \item rr.
        \item tt.
    \end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

After running this file in TeXstudio where I have already configured commands from "Options" > "Configure TeXstudio", I am receiving the above error

> Could not start default compiler: PdfLaTeX

Comment: Your code is fine. Which LaTeX distribution you use? TeXstudio is just editor.

Comment: I think you should check your LaTeX installation. Have you tried other editors or the command line?

Comment: have you installed tex (miktex or texlive) as well as texstudio?

Comment: Yes, I have installed MikTex and TexStudio both, but even in TexWorks, it is not working

Comment: I had this problem with a filename having two consecutive spaces. After removing the extra one, it was fine.